# Show that left translation on a locally compact Hausdorff group is continuous.

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, functions, continuity

Let $G$ be a locally compact Hausdorff group, and let $C_{bu}(G)$ be the set of all uniformly continuous and bounded functions $G \to \mathbb{C}$.

Define left translation, $\lambda:G \to \text{Aut}(C_{bu}(G))$ such that $(\lambda_{g}f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$.

How can I show that $\lambda$ is a continuous function?

I know that the definition of continuity on a topological group is that a function is continuous if for any open set in the image, the pre-image of it is also open. I am not sure how to check that the preimage is open in this case.

Comment: Show that it is the composition of two continuous functions.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I don't think that helps, I don't know how to show a function $G \to$Aut$(C_{bu}(G))$ is continuous

Comment: You know that the maps $g \longmapsto gf$ and $(g,f) \longmapsto gf$ are continuous. Now what is the topology you are considering on $Aut(\mathcal{C}_{ru}(G))$?

Comment: @Evian, the weak * topology

Comment: You say "uniformly continuous". Which uniform structures do you use?

Comment: @PaulFrost Good question but for topological group saying that a function is uniformly continuous is equivalent to say that the two orbital maps $g \longmapsto gf$ and $g \longmapsto fg$ are continuous with respect to the supremum norm on $\mathcal{C}_{bu}(G)$. Now for answering your question, the uniformity considered on the group is the Roelcke uniformity.

Comment: @Chris I think you want to say point wise topology. Because to speak about weak-* topology you need to have a predual.

Answer (score 1):

Recall that a net $ (T_\alpha)_\alpha \in Aut(\mathcal{C}_{bu}(G))$ converges to $T \in Aut(\mathcal{C}_{bu}(G))$ if and only if for every $f\in \mathcal{C}_{bu}(G)$ we have that $\lim_\alpha T_\alpha(f) = T(f)$.

Let $(g_\alpha)_\alpha \in G$ be a net converging to some $g\in G$ and let $f\in \mathcal{C}_{bu}(G)$. Then we can compute that $\lim_\alpha \lambda(g_\alpha)(f)= \lim_\alpha g_\alpha f = gf$ as we know that the map $g \longmapsto gf$ is orbitally continuous.